# Offset jQuery top, scroll posts

Tags: jquery

Can anyone drop a line on how to offset this from the top? I want there always to be some air above, aproximately 150px.

Original post: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/scrollto-posts-with-jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    function scroll(direction) {

        var scroll, i,
                positions = [],
                here = $(window).scrollTop(),
                collection = $('.post');

        collection.each(function() {
            positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset()['top'],10));
        });

        for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            if (direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here) { scroll = collection.get(i); break; }
            if (direction == 'prev' && i > 0 && positions[i] >= here) { scroll = collection.get(i-1); break; }
        }

        if (scroll) {
            $.scrollTo(scroll, {
                duration: 750       
            });
        }

        return false;
    }

    $("#next,#prev").click(function() {        
        return scroll($(this).attr('id'));        
    });

    $(".scrolltoanchor").click(function() {
        $.scrollTo($($(this).attr("href")), {
            duration: 750
        });
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the effect you're going for? What is it that you're trying to offset from the top?

Comment: If you check out example: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/scrollto-demo/ You see that all the posts align to the top of the browser. I want some space and in between the top of browser window and posts. Grateful if you could drop some code in the right place!

Comment: margin-top or what do you mean?

Comment: Yeah, if you check out example you see that the first "post" has an initial space above it. When you hit the next button I just want post  #two to replace the position of post #1. As it is now post #one first aligns with the top of the browser then post #two does same. I always want to keep the initial space existing over the first post. Sry if the exclamation is a bit messy...I am not too bright when it comes to handling jQ, grateful to you problem solvers!

Comment: Here is a example of the exakt result I am looking for. http://www.dbworks.pro/

Answer (score 0):

The scrollTo function actually has offset capability built into it. So, if you want your scrolling to go to 150 pixels above the post, you can change your call to the scrollTo function to this:

```
$.scrollTo(scroll, {
            duration: 750,
            offset: {top: -150}
        });
```

See [here](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo#settings) for a list of options that scrollTo has and their explanations.

Comment: Thanks, although adding this just seems to break everything. It won't slide to next or previous. This is the exact desired effect I'm trying to achieve: http://www.dbworks.pro/